# How to upload an image to firebase storage and then return the download url?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, react-native-firebase

Im trying to upload an image to firebase storage in a react-native project, then return the download URL once upload is complete.

this is what I tried:
EDITED:

```
const uploadImg = async (dispatch, uri, uid, mime = 'image/png') => {
    console.log('Starting image upload...');

    dispatch({ type: types.UPLOAD_IMG, info: 'Uploading profile image...' });
    const uploadUri = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? uri.replace('file://', '') : uri;

    return (imageRef = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(uid)
        .child('profileImg')
        .putFile(uploadUri, { contentType: 'image/png' })
        .catch((err) => {
            uploadImgFail(dispatch, err.message);
        }));
};
```

part of implementation:

```
uploadImg(dispatch, img, userCredential.user.uid)
    .then((imgRef) => {
        const imgUrl = imgRef.getDownloadURL();
        console.log('uploaded Image URL: ' + imgUrl)
        uploadImgSuccess(dispatch, 'Profile image upload successful...');
        // rest of action
}
```

the problem is the download URL isn't returned by the function, I get unhandled promise rejection: "can't find variable: imgUrl"

Any help on achieving this with `react-native-firebase`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to actually return a value from `uploadImg`.  Right now it's returning nothing.  Add a `return` keyword before `imageRef.putFile()` to return the promise that its chained promise returns.

Comment: oh probably because getDownloadURL() returns a promise?

Comment: Yes, it does return a promise, but even if it didn't, you would still need for your function to return the result of the first promise in the chain.